# passing the correct type from the Controller to the View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Got this error message while trying to load view:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.String]]',
but this dictionary requires a model item of type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[HelloWorld.Models.P]'.
```

Could it be from not passing the correct type from the Controller to the View?

Here's the model:

```
public class P
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ImportID { set; get; }
    public virtual string MicroName { set; get; }
}
```

Here's the DBContext definition:

```
public DbSet<P> Ps { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  //REMAPPING TABLE NAMES 
  modelBuilder.Entity<P>()
.ToTable("SomeTable_With_Really_LongName_tbl");

base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Here's the Controller action:

```
public ActionResult ListP()
{

var model = (from p in _db.Ps
 select new
 {
p.ImportID,
 p.MicroName
 }).Take(10);

return View(model);
}
```

Here's the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<HelloWorld.Models.P>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List P";
}

<h2>List P</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            ImportID
        </th>
        <th>
            MicroName
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImportID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MicroName)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think that

```
var model = (from p in _db.Ps
 select new
 {
p.ImportID,
 p.MicroName
 }).Take(10);
```

is returning the Import ID and Name where it should be returning a enumerator of P

```
var model = _db.Ps.OrderBy(f => f.[FieldName]).Take(10);
```

Comment: Michael, 

Sorry I have an 'order by' right before the Select New.
How do you go about setting the order?

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because the View is expecting a model of type `IEnumerable<HelloWorld.Models.P>`, but you are passing it a model that is a collection of Anonymous Type.

In the controller try this:

```
public ActionResult ListP()
{
    var model = (from p in _db.Ps
                select p).Take(10);

    return View(model);
}
```

OR

```
public ActionResult ListP()
{
    var model = (from p in _db.Ps
                select new P
                {
                    ImportID = p.ImportID,
                    MicroName = p.MicroName
                }).Take(10);

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daryl for the tip

i figured out how to put in the order by:

            var model = (from p in _db.Ps
                         orderby p.CreateDate descending
                         select p).Take(10);