# How to pass custom linq query to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm learning and testing how to pass custom linq results

code from controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    const int pageSize = 5;
    return View(from p in db.powners
                  where p.petowner.StartsWith("")
                  orderby p.petowner.Skip(0).Take(pageSize).ToList()
                  select new { p.ownerid, p.petowner, p.ostreet });

}
```

code from view:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Mvc4test2.Models.powner>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<link href="../../Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<h2>Find owner</h2>

<p>
@using (@Html.BeginForm("index", "lookup", FormMethod.Get))
{    
    <b>Search</b>@Html.TextBox("search")<input type="submit" value="search" />
}
</p>
<table id="ownertable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.petowner)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ostreet)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
    <td>
        <a href="">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ownerid) </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.petowner)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ostreet)
    </td>

</tr>
}

</table>
```

What I have tried:

```
@model IEnumerable<Mvc4test2.Models.powner>
```

and

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Mvc4test2.Models.powner>
```

Get following error:

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`3[System.Int32,System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Mvc4test2.Models.powner]'.`

Any idea how to pass this query to view and have it work as expected.
Of course later I will use a variable at Skip(0).  I have to learn to pass it first.
Thanks

Comment: This expression works:

Answer (score 4):

Don't pass anonymous type. Here I suggest you have two options. If `Powner` class has only 3 fields (ownerid, petowner, ostreet) then `select new { p.ownerid, p.petowner, p.ostreet }` line in your query is redundant.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     const int pageSize = 5;
     var model = (from p in db.powners
                 where p.petowner.StartsWith("")
                 orderby p.petowner.Skip(0).Take(pageSize) select p).ToList();
     return View(model);
}
```

or if your `Powner` class is more complicated and your view has to display only ownerid, petowner and ostreet than you should create view model class which contains of these 3 properties only. Example:

```
public class PownerViewModel
{
    public int OwnerId {get;set;}     // You should modify these
    public string Petowner {get;set;} // properties types
    public string OStreet {get;set;}  // since I don't exactly know what they are
}
```

.. and modify your query:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     const int pageSize = 5;
     var model = from p in db.powners
                 where p.petowner.StartsWith("")
                 orderby p.petowner.Skip(0).Take(pageSize)
                 select new PownerViewModel()
                 {
                     OwnerId = p.ownerid,  
                     Petowner = p.petowner,
                     OStreet = p.ostreet                          
                  };
     return View(model);
}
```

.. and of course change model type in your view:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PownerViewModel>
```

P.S. There can be some errors or typos since I coded right here.

Comment: This expression works: return View(db.powners.Where(x => x.petowner.StartsWith(search) || search == null).OrderBy(x => x.petowner).Skip(5).Take(pageSize).ToList());  What would be a regular linq to sql expression equivalent to this.  Isn't this one called lamada or something like that?

Comment: @user560131, yes, this is alternative way of querying.

Comment: Works:return View(db.powners.Where(x => x.petowner.StartsWith(search) || search == null).OrderBy(x => x.petowner).Skip(5).Take(pageSize).ToList());                          Doesn't work: return View(db.powners
                             .Where(p => p.petowner.StartsWith(search))
                             .OrderBy(p => p.petowner).Skip(0).Take(5)
          .Select(p => new { p.ownerid, p.petowner, p.ostreet }).ToList());  WHY does the one with select NOT work?  Guess Lambda doesn't require a Select clause.  However, 2nd query works webforms app. Why doesn't it work in MVC?

Comment: Because, as I already said, your model is of anonymous type when you use `.Select(p => new { p.ownerid, p.petowner, p.ostreet })` and your view is strongly typed. I don't understand why you need select, in this case it is redundant. However, if you really need select use `.Select(p => new Powner { ownerid = p.ownerid, petowner = p.petowner, ostreet = p.ostreet })`.

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavskyi hi...can u tell me or can u provide any link for how to get these query result in jquery method in view?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the return type of your query in the Index controller. You should return enumerator of P.

Please check the below link:

[passing the correct type from the Controller to the View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942729/passing-the-correct-type-from-the-controller-to-the-view)